# Using 'if ( empty()' except form

Tags: php, joomla

With some php editing for a Joomla site, I was trying to to figure out how to redirect users who clicked old links for deleted items. So in the `\components\com_blah\views\item\view.html.php` I put the following code:

```
if ( empty($item->id) )
{
    $msg = JText::_( 'This item does not exist' );
    $mainframe->redirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_blah&view=item&layout=detailed'),$msg);
}
```

Which works when trying to access the form at `\components\com_blah\views\item\default\form.php`

However, using url `index.php?option=com_blah&view=item&layout=form` does not allow the user to access the form to create a new item because of the redirect for no id being found.

So how can I change the above code so it will work except for the form page?

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should set varible which store value as he is visiting product or going to add new item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an extra condition to your `if`:

1. If item_id is empty and
2. layout != "form"

Giving this code:

```
$layout = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('layout');
if ( empty($item->id) && ($layout != "form"))
{
    $msg = JText::_( 'This item does not exist' );
    $mainframe->redirect(
       JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_blah&view=item&layout=detailed'),
       $msg);
}
```

Comment: Don't use the global `$_REQUEST` - use the tools that are provided for input sanitization. If you are within your view.html.php, you can use `$this->getLayout()` to get the current layout, otherwise, you should get it from the application input object. `$layout = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('layout');`

Comment: @nrider Answer updated, using joomla API. Please, use the new version.